# Extract data from a HTML table and convert to JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a HTML table that I want to parse and convert to JSON.

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="height: 24px;">
 <tr class="tr-hover">
  <th rowspan="15" scope="row">Network</th>
  <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">Technology</a></td>
  <td class="nfo"><a href="#" class="link-network-detail collapse">GSM</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="tr-toggle">
  <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">2G bands</a></td>
  <td class="nfo">GSM 900 / 1800 - SIM 1 & SIM 2</td>
 </tr>  
 <tr class="tr-toggle">
  <td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=gprs">GPRS</a></td>
  <td class="nfo">Class 12</td>
 </tr>  
 <tr class="tr-toggle">
  <td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=edge">EDGE</a></td>
  <td class="nfo">Yes</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In the above table

```
<th rowspan="15" scope="row">Network</th>
```

JSON array name should be "Network".

```
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">Technology</a></td>
```

Technology is a subheading of Network, so it must be a JSON element inside the JSON array. The values coming inside Technology array should be the values from

```
<td class="nfo"><a href="#" class="link-network-detail collapse">GSM</a></td>
```

I hope my question is clear. How can i do that?

Comment: better title: extract data from a HTML table and convert to JSON

Comment: I think you can do what you want with plain javascript.

Comment: this might be help ful (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9927335/2749470)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an answer using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) and [JSON](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) as dependencies:

```
final String HTML = "<table cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"height: 24px;\">\r\n<tr class=\"tr-hover\">\r\n<th rowspan=\"15\" scope=\"row\">Network</th>\r\n<td class=\"ttl\"><a href=\"network-bands.php3\">Technology</a></td>\r\n<td class=\"nfo\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"link-network-detail collapse\">GSM</a></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr class=\"tr-toggle\">\r\n<td class=\"ttl\"><a href=\"network-bands.php3\">2G bands</a></td>\r\n<td class=\"nfo\">GSM 900 / 1800 - SIM 1 & SIM 2</td>\r\n</tr>   \r\n<tr class=\"tr-toggle\">\r\n<td class=\"ttl\"><a href=\"glossary.php3?term=gprs\">GPRS</a></td>\r\n<td class=\"nfo\">Class 12</td>\r\n</tr>   \r\n<tr class=\"tr-toggle\">\r\n<td class=\"ttl\"><a href=\"glossary.php3?term=edge\">EDGE</a></td>\r\n<td class=\"nfo\">Yes</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
Element table = document.select("table").first();
String arrayName = table.select("th").first().text();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
Elements ttls = table.getElementsByClass("ttl");
Elements nfos = table.getElementsByClass("nfo");
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0, l = ttls.size(); i < l; i++) {
    String key = ttls.get(i).text();
    String value = nfos.get(i).text();
    jo.put(key, value);
}
jsonArr.put(jo);
jsonObj.put(arrayName, jsonArr);
System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```

Output (formatted):

```
{
    "Network": [
        {
            "2G bands": "GSM 900 / 1800 - SIM 1 & SIM 2",
            "Technology": "GSM",
            "GPRS": "Class 12",
            "EDGE": "Yes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Works properly.

Comment: Hi , its a good solution but can you tell me how to handel nested tables ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
TableElements("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp","customers");
    }
    public static void TableElements(String link,String id) `<br>
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
//Provide the ChromeDriver location 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/Ecllipse/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(link);
        WebElement element;
        //Getting the Table code
`       try
        {
            element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
        `}
        `catch(Exception e)
        `{
            `element = driver.findElement(By.className(id));
        `}
        `String html = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        //Formatting to Table code to Html
        `b.append(html);
        `b.insert(0,"<html><body><table>");
        `b.append("</table></body></html>");

    `Document document = Jsoup.parse(b.toString());
    `Element table = document.select("table").first();

    //Selecting Th and Td 
    `JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
    `Elements ttls = table.getElementsByTag("th");
    `Elements nfos = table.getElementsByTag("td");
    `String key = "";
    `String value = "";

    //Adding Td to Th in JSON array
    `for(int i=0,j=0;i<nfos.size();i++,j++)
    `{`<br>
        `if(j<ttls.size())
        `{`<br>
            `key = ttls.get(j).text();
            `value = nfos.get(i).text();
        `}
        `else
        `{
            `j=0;
            `key = ttls.get(j).text();
            `value = nfos.get(i).text();
        `}`<br>
        `JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        `try 
        `{
            `jo.put(key, value);
        `}`<br>
        `catch (JSONException e)
        `{
            `System.out.println("Unable to add objects to Json Array!");
        `}`<br>
        `jsonArr.put(jo);`<br>
    `}`<br>
    `String ji = "";`<br>
    `int j = 0;`<br>

    //Converting JSON array to Character array and removing unwanted characters
    `for (char ch: jsonArr.toString().toCharArray()) `<br>
    `{`<br>
        `if(ch == '}')`<br>
        `{`<br>
            `j++;`<br>
            `if(j%ttls.size() != 0)`<br>
                `ch = ' ';`<br>
        `}`<br>
        `else if(ch == '{')`<br>
        `{`<br>
            `if(j%ttls.size() != 0)`<br>
                `ch = ' ';`<br>
        `}`<br>
        `ji+=ch;`<br>
    `}`<br>
    `System.out.println(ji);`<br>
    `driver.close();`<br>
`}`<br>
}
```

Comment: copy both the codes, in the table elements call pass Website link and either table id or class.