# Get Table data in json format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html

Hello everyone I'm trying to get table data in json format here is my table

```
   <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>srno</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jhon One</td>
      <td>Doe one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jhon two</td>
      <td>Doe Two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>
  convert
</button>
```

the result which i am getting is this

```
{
    "0": {
        "1",
        "Jhon One",
        "Doe one"
    }
    ,
    "1": {
        "2",
        "Jhon two",
        "Doe Two"
    }
}
```

using the below javascript

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var json = html2json();
  alert(json);
});

function html2json() {
  var json = '{';
  var otArr = [];
  // var i = 1;
  var tbl2 = $('table tbody tr').each(function(e) {
    x = $(this).children();
    var itArr = [];
    x.each(function() {
      itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
    });
    otArr.push('"' + e + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
  })
  json += otArr.join(",") + '}'

  return json;
}
```

but i want to add key to every value and the number should start from one and not zero.

i have a set of desire result and it should look like this
any help is appreciated

```
  {
        "1": {
           no: "1",
           name:"Jhon One",
           lastname "Doe one"
        }
        ,
         "2": {
           no: "1",
           name:"Jhon two",
           lastname "Doe two"
        }

    }
```

here is the fiddel link which i have tried

https://jsfiddle.net/k228n2bn/

Comment: i hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript) stackoverflow link might help you

Comment: Not a great idea to build JSON by means of string concatenation. sonicblis and Félix have done it the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the following line

```
otArr.push('"' + e + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
```

to

```
otArr.push('"' + (e+1) + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
```

The parenthesis will add the values as numbers not strings.

Also, add `keys` array for internal object keys.

```
function html2json() {
   var json = '{';
   var otArr = [];
  // var i = 1;
   var tbl2 = $('table tbody tr').each(function(e) {        
      x = $(this).children();
      var itArr = [];
      var keys = ['no','name','lastname'];
      x.each(function(i) {
         itArr.push('"' + keys[i] + '":"' + $(this).text() + '"');
      });
      otArr.push('"' + (e+1) + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
   })
   json += otArr.join(",") + '}'

   return json;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `e` to a Number and add one to it like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k228n2bn/1/).

```
function html2json() {
  var json = '{';
  var otArr = [];
  // var i = 1;
  var tbl2 = $('table tbody tr').each(function(e) {
    x = $(this).children();
    var itArr = [];
    x.each(function() {
      itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
    });
    otArr.push('"' + (Number(e) + 1) + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
  })
  json += otArr.join(",") + '}'

  return json;
}
```

The json you're returning is not valid though.  You may want to do something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k228n2bn/7/) if you can to simplify and ensure valid json and to create your objects from any table structure.

```
function html2json() {   
  var otArr = [];
  var tblHeaders = Array.from($('table thead tr')
    .children())
    .map(header => $(header).text());  
  var tbl2 = $('table tbody tr').each(function(e) {        
    const values = Array.from($(this).children());
    const row = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < tblHeaders.length; i++){        
        row[tblHeaders[i]] = $(values[i]).text();
    }
    otArr.push({
        [e+1]: row
    })      
  })
  json = JSON.stringify(otArr);  
  return json;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort but how can i show the key to the value 
like name: jhon plz see my question again in last i have shown the desired result

Comment: No problem.  This will create your desired result from any table, not just the one in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `e+1`

change `otArr.push('"' + e + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');`

to
`otArr.push('"' + (e+1) + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');`

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var json = html2json(); 
});

function html2json() {
  var json = '{';
  var otArr = [];
   
  var tbl2 = $('table tbody tr').each(function(e) {
    x = $(this).children();
    var itArr = [];
    x.each(function(e) {
   
      var items='';
       if(e == 0){
          items +='no : "'+ $(this).text()+'"';
          
       } 
       if(e == 1){
          items +='name : "' +$(this).text()+'"'; 
       }
       if(e == 2){
          items +='email : "' +$(this).text()+'"'; 
       }
       
       itArr.push(items);
       
    });
   
    otArr.push('"' + (e+1) + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
  })
  json += otArr.join(",") + '}'
alert(json);
  return json;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>srno</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jhon One</td>
      <td>Doe one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jhon two</td>
      <td>Doe Two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>
  convert
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time man plz check my question in bottom for desired result . i want to add key to all values.

Comment: this is the result i am looking for 

{
        "1": {
           no: "1",
           name:"Jhon One",
           lastname "Doe one"
        }
        ,
         "2": {
           no: "1",
           name:"Jhon two",
           lastname "Doe two"
        }

    }

Comment: but still thr is a problem  {"srno":"\"1\""} value should not be in curly braces it should be comma sperated plz check my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use theads as keys for the generated objects.
Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k228n2bn/6/).

```
function html2json() {
  var $table = $('table');
  var $ths = $table.find('thead>tr>th');
  var rows = {};
  $table.find('tbody>tr').each(function () {
    var row = {};
    $(this).children().each(function (index) {
      row[$ths[index].textContent] = this.textContent;
    });
    rows[row.srno] = row;
  });
  return JSON.stringify(rows);
}
```