# Unpacking json string in Java which is created of dynamic html table

Tags: java, json

I have created a Json string from my dynamic html table using the following link
[How to convert the following table to JSON with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript).

Now, how do I read this in java when my String looks like below:

```
{"myrows": [{
      "Event type":"Vitality Health Check",
      "Estimated number of insured employees":"100",
      "Estimated number of uninsured employees":"100",
      "Cost per Uninsured employee (incl VAT)":"10000",
      "Estimated total cost for uninsured employees (incl VAT)":"10000"
  }]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for editing Arek. will remember for next time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing below.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(INPUT_JSON_STRING);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("myrows"));
    WellnessEventDetail wellnessEventDetail = null;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
        wellnessEventDetail = new WellnessEventDetail();
        JSONObject jsonObj  = array.getJSONObject(i);
        wellnessEventDetail.setEventType(jsonObj.getString("Event type"));
        .......
    }
```