# Get the all the text (single and multi-line) between HTML table tags <table><tbody><th><tr><td> and generate json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the below HTML Table and I want to get the data between the tags which are sometimes single line and sometimes multi-line.

```
<table>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Device Name</th>
        <th>IP Address </th>
        <th>MAC Address </th>
        <th>Registered </th>
        <th>Subscribers </th>
        <th>Events </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
    CM
   </td>
        <td>
    -
   </td>
        <td>192.168.7.110&nbsp;</td>
        <td>506182488323&nbsp;</td>
        <td>XYZ
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;Shkdsd30ec1
        </td>
        <td>Events
        </td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to generate the JSON with this table like the below code using javascript

```
{
  "Role" : "CM",
  "Device Name" : "-",
  "IP Address" : "192.168.7.110",
  "MAC Address" : "506182488323",
  "Registered" : "XYZ",
  "Subscribers" : "Shkdsd30ec1",
  "Events" : "Events"
}
```

If there are more  tags with  the key should get incremented like Role->Role1->Role2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have this table alone in your HTML body...

```js
let t = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
let trs = t[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
let oKeys = [], oVals = [];
let ths = trs[0].getElementsByTagName("th");
let tds = trs[1].getElementsByTagName("td");
ths = Array.from(ths);
tds = Array.from(tds);
ths.map( item => {
  oKeys.push(item.innerText);
  return ;
});
tds.map( item => {
  oVals.push(item.innerText);
  return ;
});
console.log("O keys ", oKeys);
console.log("oVals ", oVals);
let newObj = {};
oKeys.map( (key, i) => {
  let val = oVals[i];
  Object.assign(newObj, {[key] : val })
});
console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Device Name</th>
        <th>IP Address </th>
        <th>MAC Address </th>
        <th>Registered </th>
        <th>Subscribers </th>
        <th>Events </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
    CM
   </td>
        <td>
    -
   </td>
        <td>192.168.7.110&nbsp;</td>
        <td>506182488323&nbsp;</td>
        <td>XYZ
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;Shkdsd30ec1
        </td>
        <td>Events
        </td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

newObj holds your desired data. You can add more to the above logic..

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery for dom selection, this JS code should work

```
var myRows = [];
var headersText = [];
var $headers = $("th");

// Loop through grabbing everything
var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
  $cells = $(this).find("td");
  myRows[index] = {};

  $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
    // Set the header text
    if(headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
      headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
    }
    // Update the row object with the header/cell combo
    myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).text();
  });
});

// Let's put this in the object like you want and convert to JSON (Note: jQuery will also do this for you on the Ajax request)
var myObj = {
    "myrows": myRows
};
console.log(myRows);
```

this code snippet was collected from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927335/1648286)