# How to convert a very large table into a specific javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I want to make a very large array of data that I found on [this website](https://www.ign.com/wikis/little-alchemy-2/Little_Alchemy_2_Cheats_-_List_of_All_Combinations). I copied the large table from that website in to my project:

[image]

This is an example of that table:

```
<tr>
  <td>Acid Rain</td>
  <td>
    rain, smoke / rain, smog / rain, sickness / cloud, smoke / cloud, smog
    / cloud, sickness / rain, city
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to convert this table in to a javascript array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Acid Rain",
    elements: [
      ["rain", "smoke"],
      ["rain", "smog"],
      ["rain", "sickness"],
      ["cloud", "smoke"],
      ["cloud", "smog"],
      ["cloud", "sickness"],
      ["rain", "city"],
    ],
  },
  {...},
  {...}
];
```

The reason I want to convert this is because it would take way too much time to input this by hand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, parse all the `tr` elements then loop through them to get the first and the second children (which are `td` elements) then the content of the first children would be the **name** value and for the **elements**, you can split the content of second children first with a `/` then with a `,`. Check the below example snippet for more details

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

const items = Array.from(trs).map(tr => {
  const firstTd = tr.children[0].innerText;
  const secondTd = tr.children[1].innerText;
  
  const elements = secondTd.split(" / ").map(t => t.split(", "));
  
  return {
    name:firstTd,
    elements
  };
});

console.log(items)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Acid Rain</td>
    <td>
      rain, smoke / rain, smog / rain, sickness / cloud, smoke / cloud, smog
      / cloud, sickness / rain, city
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's just a one time thing you could use https://www.convertjson.com/html-table-to-json.htm to generate json based on your table to make it easier to manipulate

Comment: But I actually want to convert this to a javascript array, if that is possible

Comment: @EmielVdV If you have a valid json, you can convert it in any programming language. For javascript, just use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Although a link to an external resource may be useful, the answer should really show how to code it, providing the essential information needed. Links can break over time and this is about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the HTML with `DOMParser` and then map each table row as follows:

```js
const html = `<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:468px"><tbody><tr><td> <b>Resulting Element</b></td><td> <b>Ingredient Combination(s)</b></td></tr><tr><td> Acid Rain</td><td> rain, smoke / rain, smog / rain, sickness / cloud, smoke / cloud, smog / cloud, sickness / rain, city</td></tr><tr><td> Air</td><td> Available from start.</td></tr><tr><td> Airplane</td><td> metal, bird / steel, bird / bird, machine / bird, steam engine / bird, train / bird, car / bird, boat / bird, steamboat / bird, sailboat / metal, owl / steel, owl / steam engine, owl / metal, vulture / steel, vulture / metal, duck / steel, duck / metal, seagull / steel, seagull / metal, bat / steel, bat / metal, eagle / steel, eagle / steel, pigeon / metal, pigeon / metal, hummingbird / steel, hummingbird / metal, crow / steel, crow / owl, machine / vulture, machine / duck, machine / seagull, machine / bat, machine / eagle, machine / pigeon, machine / hummingbird, machine / crow, machine / pilot, container</td></tr><tr><td> Alarm Clock</td><td> clock, sound / clock, dawn / clock, bell / sound, watch / watch, dawn / watch, bell</td></tr><tr><td> Alchemist</td><td> human, gold / gold, philosophy</td></tr><tr><td> Alcohol</td><td> time, juice / wheat, fruit / wheat, juice / fruit, sun</td></tr><tr><td> Algae</td><td> water, plant / grass, pond / grass, lake / water, grass</td></tr><tr><td> Alien</td><td> life, space / life, galaxy / life, galaxy cluster / life, solar system / life, Mars / life, Venus / life, Mercury / life, Jupiter / life, Saturn</td></tr><tr><td> Allergy</td><td> dust, human / human, pollen</td></tr></tbody></table>`;

const {body} = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");

const result = Array.from(body.children[0].rows, ({cells: [a, b]}) => ({
    name: a.textContent.trim(),
    elements: b.textContent.trim().split(" / ").map(pair => pair.split(", "))
}));
result.shift(); // Ignore first (header) row
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to iterate by rows, and then transform them.

You can get rows using `table.rows`, and iterate by them. To get cells use `row.cells`. `cells[0]` - would be row name and `cells[1]` - would be row elements. You need to split and transform your elements, then add it to result object then array.

```
const table = document.getElementById("table");
const result = [];

// iterate by rows
for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  const row = table.rows[i];
  const rowName = row.cells[0].textContent;
  const rowElements = row.cells[1].textContent;

  result.push({
    name: rowName,
    elements: splitRowElements(rowElements)
  });
}

function splitRowElements(rowElements) {
  const splitedByComma = rowElements.split(",");
  const splitedAlsoBySlash = splitedByComma.map((element) =>
    element.split("/")
  );
  const splitedAndTrimmed = splitedAlsoBySlash.map((element) =>
    element.map((elementOfElement) => elementOfElement.trim())
  );

  return splitedAndTrimmed;
}
```

I made functioning example on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-feynman-559sw1?file=/src/index.js